# Need png optimisation/compression advice

Tags: png, compression

I have a large set of png images I am trying to compress and I would like some advice from all of the graphics experts out there :) on the best method to do this.  I have access to both a Mac and Windows machine and would like the compressed images to be as small as possible without losing any quality ().

From what I have read it seems that PNGSLIM is the best way for me to go (http://graphicsoptimization.com/blog/?p=7), has anyone used this before and would you recommend it?  Or should I just use PNGCRUSH?

Looking forward to learning from your wisdom.

**UPDATE**: When I tried to download PNGSLIM my virus checkerflagged it up as a dangerous file??

Comment: PNG is a lossless format, so you don't lose any image information (quality) when using the format. Compressions can be changed, etc., but all the image data is still there, assuming it's being done correctly.

Comment: PNGs can certainly be lossy if you change the bit-depth when saving.

Comment: That wouldn't really qualify as compression IMO

Comment: apropos to what  DA01 says in his answer, ( http://optipng.sourceforge.net/pngtech/optipng.html ) is a nice discussion of the topic which includes a list of programs.

Comment: Related question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/3162/10419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Mac I use PNGCrusher:

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/17768/pngcrusher

On Windows I use Optipng:

http://optipng.sourceforge.net/

Both basically strip out all meta information that isn't required by the browser to render it.

Comment: I've also used PNGCrusher on Mac, and it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

More tools:

- [PNGOut](http://www.ardfry.com/pngoutwin/)
- [Yahoo SmushIt (online)](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/)

For me PNGOut seems to be the best, but in a few cases SmushIt produced lower sized images. OptiPNG produced larger files than both.

There's also [Google Page Speed](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/pagespeed/), which tells you which images could be optimized...

Answer (score 1):

The tool you mentioned seems to work great for me (no virus warning). I saw a 44% decrease in file size, after a single test.

You can download here: http://people.bath.ac.uk/ea2aced/tech/png/

It also looks like a newer version may be available, according to the modified dates. I downloaded and ran `pngslim091.zip`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two, both of which are very good:

RIOT - http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/

PNGGauntlet - http://pnggauntlet.com/

Answer (score 0):

For Mac I've created [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) which runs **all** PNG optimization tools on every file and picks the best result.

It includes PNGOUT and all tools that YSmushit and PNGSLIM use, so with single drag'n'drop you have equivalent of applying all the advice of all other answers here :)

---

If you could sacrifice a little quality, then you could reduce size of PNG images by 60%-70% with lossy PNG compressor [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com) ([TinyPNG](http://tinypng.com) is equivalent tool you can use on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I use [pictureslash.com](http://pictureslash.com) its awesome, with many features :) - and free

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I see, i'll try to answer more specific then.
I would advise you to use an online service, so you wont run in to software that is only supported by specific platforms..

Comment: You should edit your actual Answer with that type of comment. The thing is right now because of how short your Answer is, and including a link, it gets flagged as possible spam / low quality answer and asks higher rep members if it should be deleted. Editing your Answer to include the comment you just made would be a great way to fix that.