# Is there a way to slightly reduce my PNG file size without much loss? Easiest way to optimize perhaps?

Tags: png, canva

I am using CANVA software which only allows files up to 25 mb and my png's are over 30.  I don't want to compress all the way down to JPG.  I'd like to keep as much detail as possible.

Comment: Please provide more detail so that you can receive useful answers.  What will you be using the PNG for, i.e. web viewing, print, banners, etc.? How did you create the PNG? Does the PNG have transparencies? What type of software do you have available for compressing your images (I don't work in Canva, so excuse me if you can do this compression directly within the program). If you don't need the transparency, most software allows you to save a high-quality jpg with little (if any) data loss--why won't this work for you?  Add more detail and someone is more likely to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tools for \*lossy\* PNG compression?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4475/tools-for-lossy-png-compression)

Comment: there are a bunch of other questions about optimizing and compressing PNG files, use the search on the top right

Comment: 'compress all the way down to JPG' is not how this works. A JPG and a PNG can be exact the same file size with the same kind of compression, what exactly is in the file makes up the file size.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts. I have no idea what that software does.

There are some hundreds of different compression methods for PNG, but normally they do not compress a file much better than the other. The applications try to simply use a good compression variant.

But something (The big file size) is telling me you are using PNG for the wrong reasons. A PNG is recommended for graphics, logos or flat designs. If your composition has a photo (Which uses much space using PNG) think of using JPG with little to no compression.

The only case you need PNG is to preserve some transparency.

Some Online programs that claim to compress your PNG, actually make a JPG compression on Photos and then save them to PNG again.

Others simply reduce a 24-bit image to 8 bit.

If you have this case, try simply re-saving the file with Gimp.

You can also take a look at similar questions. [Need png optimisation/compression advice](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3926/need-png-optimisation-compression-advice)

Answer (score -1):

If you're not to bothered by external services or tools take a look at https://tinypng.com

It's a great service which can also batch convert (multiple files at the same time).

Comment: This kind of services, what actually do is using an algorithm similar to JPG and then saving it as png, so, practically is the same as using jpg.

Comment: But I will make a test again later to confirm this.

Comment: Ok I just confirmed. It makes a 24 bit image to 8 bit pallete one.